# Why did Khudabaksh behave inconsistently in Thugs of Hindostan?

Tags: plot-explanation, thugs-of-hindostan

As seen in the trailer for *Thugs of Hindostan* and the movie, Khudabaksh (Amitabh Bacchan) and Firangi (Aamir Khan) share this dialogue

> *Firangi:* Dhoka mera swabhav hai (Deceit is my nature)
>   *Khudabaksh:* Aur bharosa mera (And trust is mine)

Khudabaksh reiterates his trusty nature through several similar dialogues in the film.

Even though Firangi infiltrates the rebel Aazad army and gives up their location to Clive of the British East India Company, Khudahbaksh entrusts Firangi with the amulet to protect Zafira and the rebel army.

However, earlier in the movie, when another spy is brought before him, Khudabaksh beheads him even though the spy asks for forgiveness and another chance to prove himself.

So why did he behave inconsistently? Why did he choose to behead one spy while trusting and giving another chance to another spy (Firangi)?

Answer (score 1):

There were 2 reasons for this behaviour on Khudabaksh's part:

1. He saw something special in Firangi (Something more close to what is known as the skill of 'judging character' or in other terms of common usage 'vibes' or vibrations) that made Khudabaksh a little hopeful about Firangi (even giving him a mild idea that Firangi might be his greatest discovery) as if Firangi would help him in fulfilling his cause (in this case - *Aazaadi* or Freedom for his kingdom from British). This is evident from one of their interactions:

   > ***Khudabaksh***: *Lekin tumhe dekhta hun to lagta hai, tumhare ander kuch hai jo chhatpata raha hai.. Raasta dhoondh raha hai.. Aazaad hona chatta hai..
   >   Shayad hum wo zariya banein tumhari aazaadi ka.. Ab ye to waqt hi batayega ke tum hamari sabse badi khoj ho ya sabse badi galti..*
   >
   > (***Khudabaksh***: But when I look at you...I see someone who is uneasy. You're seeking something. Looking for a path. Wanting to be free. Maybe we are the bridge to your freedom. Only time will tell if you're my greatest discovery. Or my greatest mistake.)
2. The point at which Khudabaksh entrusts Firangi to protect Zafira, he (Khudabaksh) had no other choice but to chose Firangi as he was not sure if he (Khudabaksh) is going to be around anymore (rather alive) to protect Zafira and he knew that he had to give this responsibility to somebody before leaving and the only other person present there (who in Khudabaksh's eyes is also capable to do this job) was Firangi, which is clear from the below conversation:

   > ***Khudabaksh***: *Firangi!! Kambakht waqt bahut kam hai.. Tumhari takdeer aur fitrat to nahi Badal sakta, sirf ek kaam kar do mere liye.. Zafira itni si thi tabse meri nigrani mein hai, nazar tak lagne nahi di maine kisi ki us par.. Magar aj, aj shayad mushkil ho jaye.. Aj Zafira ki hifazat tumhe karni hogi..*
   >
   > (***Khudabaksh***: Firangi! Time is running out. I cannot change your fate or your nature...but just do one thing for me. Zafira was young when she was given into my care. I did not let her come to any harm. But today...I cannot protect her. You must protect her today.)